# Can't connect to network

Tags: configuration

It always gets stuck at about 10% and then nothing happens. I don't have any idea on what's wrong, though I use a university connection with several things blocked but the bridges wont work either.

```
29/10/2015 01:12:51.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29/10/2015 01:12:51.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29/10/2015 01:12:51.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29/10/2015 01:12:51.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
29/10/2015 01:12:51.200 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\Ani's\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
29/10/2015 01:12:58.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
29/10/2015 01:12:58.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
29/10/2015 01:13:17.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
29/10/2015 01:13:19.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:38980 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
29/10/2015 01:13:19.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:47779 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
29/10/2015 01:13:19.600 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 169.229.59.75:46328 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
29/10/2015 01:13:32.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
29/10/2015 01:13:32.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29/10/2015 01:13:32.300 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```